# set_relation not working in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a controller like this:

```
function index()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_relation('name','parttype','type');

    $crud->set_table('part');
    $crud->set_subject('Items');

    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

I expected a dropdown field on the ADD/EDIT screens for the field "type" and for that dropdown to have options populated from parttypes table. But this code just returns text fields.

Here are my tables:

**PARTTYPE TABLE**

id -int,autocrement

name - varchar (500)

furl - varchar(500)

**PART TABLE**

id -int,autocrement

name - varchar (500)

type - varchar(500)

model - varchar (500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are doing it wrong, I think the solution that you are looking for is this:

```
$crud->set_relation('type','parttype','name');
```